# Equivalent R function for Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I’m trying to find the following equivalent function for R in matlab

```
qt(p, df, ncp)
```

So I have probability, degree of freedom and delta.
But in Matlab the function is only

```
tinv(y, nu)
```

That is

```
tinv(p, df)
```

So how can I calculate the same quantile function in Matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a way to calculate the quantiles for the noncentral student t distribution.

This can be achieved with [`nctinv`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/nctinv.html):

```
X = nctinv(P,NU,DELTA)
```

I must admit it is a bit hard to find as there is no reference to this in the documentation of `tinv`.